# Milnor's example for hearing the shape of drums

Tags: riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory, laplacian, integer-lattices

I heard that the first counter example for the Kac's question "Can we hear the shape of drums?" is given by John Milnor, as two 16-dimensional tori that are isospectral but not isometric. I found the original 1-page paper of Milnor that explains why two tori are isospectral. Also, we can show that by using the theory of theta functions and modular forms, which is explained in detail in Don Zagier's book "123 of modular forms".

However, I can't find the reference for non-isometricity of two tori. I found that two tori are $E_8 \oplus E_8$ and $\Lambda_{16}$ (where the latter one is called Barnes-Wall lattice), but I'm not sure how to show that two corresponding tori aren't isometric. (In fact, it is hard to describe the latter lattices explicitly.) Could anyone provide a brief explanation or a good reference for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's in Conway The Sensual Quadratic Form, Ebeling Lattices and Codes, Conway and Sloan SPLAG which means Sphere Packing, Lattices and Groups.

Comment: review   Conway recommends    https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183555145

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you very much!

Comment: @WillJagy I briefly skim through the books, but I couldn't find the explicit description of the Witt's 16-dimensional lattice (I'm not sure if this is the same one that is called as Barnes-Wall lattice). In page 38 of the first book, it saids that the lattices are introduced in Witt's paper that is written in German. I found that but I couldn't read it because I can't speak German... In case of the first lattice ($E_8 \oplus E_8$) it has very explicit description since $E_8$ does, which are also given in Wikipedia. But I can't find such description for the latter one.

Comment: Also, I wonder how to show that two lattices are actually different. It is true that two tori corresponding to the lattices are isomorphic if and only if the lattices are isomorphic in a sense that one can transform one lattice to the other one via linear transformation in $SO(16)$?

Comment: Try http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/  and http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/index.html#16D   and  three versions of BW16  http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/LAMBDA16.html  http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/BW16.html   http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/BW16H.html     and more material. Details, not always enough, are in SPLAG  Here is a pdf of new SPLAG material by Sloane, I forgot he has an `e' on his name  http://neilsloane.com/doc/splag3.pdf

Comment: "It is true that two tori corresponding to the lattices are isomorphic if and only if the lattices are isomorphic in a sense that one can transform one lattice to the other one via linear transformation in SO(16)?"   Yes.  Here's a sketch of the proof: a flat n-dimensional torus has a universal cover that's an n-dimensional inner product space, and since this construction is functorial an isomorphism of such flat tori gives an isomorphism of these inner product spaces.